# android pre populate preferences dynamically

Tags: java, android, preferences

I would like to check programmatically whether an sd card is installed, and if yes, give the user the choice to switch between external and internal storage.

I have my other static settings organized inside a preferences.xml.

It seems that I have to rewrite all the settings of the xml file in code if I start to work with preferences more dynamically.

Or is there an option to enhance the preferences from the xml with preferences from code which get used just once needed?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Instead of asking the exploit answer, share your tried approach the problems you faced on that if not found in any StackOverflow questions

Comment: you are right, I could have been more explicit, I solved it, I will post the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself, it looks a bit clumsy, but it works.

Once again: My problem is that I have certain setting options pre configured in an xml file as described here:
[Preferences with XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings)

Here is my preferences.xml:

```html
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/download_header">
        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            app:key="dl_background"
            app:title="@string/background_behaviour"
            app:defaultValue="false"/>
        <ListPreference
            app:title="@string/dl_qual"
            app:defaultValue="@string/low_qual"
            app:key="dl_qual"
            app:entries="@array/dl_qual_arry"
            app:entryValues="@array/dl_qual_arry"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/tc_header">
        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            app:key="tc_installed"
            app:title="@string/tc_behaviour"
            app:defaultValue="false"/>
        <ListPreference
            app:title="@string/dl_dir_root"
            app:key="dl_dir_root"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here you can define arrays which map to ListPrefrence objects.

Each option list is then populated from a resource xml file holding the actual list entries.

I used this approach for the first ListPreference "dl_qual" above.

This is the resource.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="dl_qual_arry">
        <item>Higher quality (128kbps)</item>
        <item>Lower quality (64kbps)</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

But then I had the idea to insert a ListPreference where the values of the options list are only known at runtime.

This is my second ListPreference above "dl_dir_root".

I was too lazy to rewrite (and read how to do it in advance) the complete settings activity from code.

So I ended up with this SettingsFragment inside my SettingsActivity:

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        //First, lets check whether we have initialized preferences already
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        String selectedDir = prefs.getString("dl_dir_root", "INIT");

        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceScreen();
        ListPreference  dlDirRoot = root.findPreference("dl_dir_root");
        CharSequence[] arryValues = BBCWorldServiceDownloaderUtils.getStoragePaths(getContext());
        CharSequence[] arryEntrys = BBCWorldServiceDownloaderUtils.getStoragePaths(getContext());
        dlDirRoot.setEntries(arryEntrys);
        dlDirRoot.setEntryValues(arryValues);


        if(selectedDir.equals("INIT")) {
            //Initialize value/index
            dlDirRoot.setDefaultValue(arryValues[0]);
            dlDirRoot.setValueIndex(0);
        }
        else{
            //Position at already selected value/index
            dlDirRoot.setDefaultValue(selectedDir);
            dlDirRoot.setValue(selectedDir);
            dlDirRoot.setValueIndex(dlDirRoot.findIndexOfValue(selectedDir));

        }
    }
}
```

The pre defined xml is applied first, then the ListPreference object for "dl_dir_root" is acessed and the options are added:

```
ListPreference  dlDirRoot = root.findPreference("dl_dir_root");
    CharSequence[] arryValues = BBCWorldServiceDownloaderUtils.getStoragePaths(getContext());
    CharSequence[] arryEntrys = BBCWorldServiceDownloaderUtils.getStoragePaths(getContext());
    dlDirRoot.setEntries(arryEntrys);
    dlDirRoot.setEntryValues(arryValues);
```

The rest is checking/keeping state between the calls to the activity.

If anyone knows of a more elegant way, I would be curious.

Best

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Add this to manifest for install app on sd card if is possible:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```

To verify is sd card writable and readable use this method:

```
private boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
       return Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);}
```

To get folder of appfiles on sdCard (`externalStorageVolumes[0]` is primary folder):

```
File[] externalStorageVolumes =
    ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(getApplicationContext(), null);
```

[Oficial documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#java)